# How can I have a generic Deserializer for Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro-tools

I am underway a migrational change from a `monolithic` to `micro-services` architecture, So we have planned to use `Kafka` as the broker.

I have been using the **kafka-client** dependency in my project
Therefore for every topic I have a different purpose and a different Object being passed onto the broker,
When doing this serialization isn't an issue on the producer front, but when I want to consume I am having to write a Deserializer for every Object separately, Can I have a generic `Deserializer`? If yes any examples?

Comment: Are you using a schema registry?

Comment: No as of now i am not using schema registry, will using a schema registry be helpful in addressing my issue? and where can i find relevant references for it ?

Comment: Yes, a schema registry is useful - you query it for the key+value schemas and it'll tell you what sort of deserializer you need (Avro, JSON, Protobuf).  I'd read through the docs at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html as start.

Comment: As you mentioned you are publishing different objects on different topics. Do you have single consumer to consume all topics ?  if yes than schema registry will not help here as you will have to write different consumers for all topics. well that's the right way to do though.

Answer (score 0):

based on the topic name u can redirect to the required method which can deserialize the msg.
like, create a Dictionary in which the Key can be the topic name and the value will be the respective deserializer method.
Dictionary<string, Action> registeredDelegates = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

Comment: Thanks,
This really helped.